# stop the php from appearing above background image

Tags: php, html, css

My php script content is appearing above my background image even the background image is set inside the html tag inside my css, how can I get the image to be behind the text

[image: Image:]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Secret Diary</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <?php
  session_start();
  if (array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];
  }
  if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)){
    echo "Logged In! <a href='index.php?logout=1'>Log Out</a>";
  } else {
    header("location: index.php");
  }
  ?>

</head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    html{
    background: url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.center{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

Comment: Your HTML output is in the head, when it should be in the body.

Comment: `session_start();` should be used at the very start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your `PHP` inbetween the `<body>` tags

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 
  if(array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)){
      $_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];
  }
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Secret Diary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)){
        echo "Logged In! <a href='index.php?logout=1'>Log Out</a>";
      } else {
        header("location: index.php");
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

also update the css line `html{` to be `body` instead

```
body {
  background: url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: `session_start();` should be used at the very start before any html

Comment: @PaulSeal What do you mean it doesnt work? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm having the same result as before, the "logged in" text is still above the background image. I copied your code exactly.

Comment: @PaulSeal Try in another browser to make sure that its not caching the page.

Comment: @MasterYoda That fixed it! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of echoing PHP where you excecute it, store it for later. Your current method (echo as you go) will result in difficult code, just like you're experiencing now.

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)){
    $loggedinText = "Logged In! <a href='index.php?logout=1'>Log Out</a>";
} 
/*
   All your content here,
   and when you're ready for it:
*/
echo $loggedinText;
```

---

Offtopic: It is considered good practice if you split html and PHP into seperate files. You place the html in a html file, and place it into a variable with php using file_get_contents.

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)){
    $loggedinText = "Logged In! <a href='index.php?logout=1'>Log Out</a>";
    $template = file_get_contents("example.html");
    // Here you do ALL YOUR OTHER LOGIC
    // _nothing_ should echo here, until:
    // And then only at the end of your file:
    echo $template;
} else{
    header("Location: not_logged_in.html");
}
```

As you can see, you can easily read *functionallity* without html that distracts you. Now only logged in users can even see your template. From a security perspective, this will also help.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me as well as the other users post. I haven't split file into html/php yet, I want to get this working first

Comment: I think you're implementing it incorrectly then, because there isn't a lot in this code that *can* go wrong :)